# Biblatex package options do not apply correctly anymore

Tags: biblatex, package-options

I use `biblatex` to create my bibliography and citations in my LaTeX document. Now as I want to change some options for the citation style. The changes I made to the biblatex options do not apply anymore. This is my minimum working example:

.tex document:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper,numbers=noenddot,listof=flat]{scrbook}

\usepackage[
backend=bibtex,
style=authoryear-icomp,
isbn=false,
pagetracker=false,
maxbibnames=50,
maxcitenames=2,
autocite=inline,
block=space,
backref=false,
backrefstyle=three+,
date=short,
hyperref=true
]{biblatex}
\bibliography{literatur}

\begin{document}

Some Text and a cite \parencite[see][p.~5]{russell2009dojo}.

Now another text with the same cite \parencite[see][p.~5]{russell2009dojo}

And the same book but another page \parencite[see][p.~6]{russell2009dojo}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

literatur.bib:

```
@book{russell2009dojo,
Author = {Russell, M.A.},
Date-Added = {2013-06-17 14:01:47 +0000},
Date-Modified = {2013-07-01 08:58:16 +0000},
Isbn = {9780596516482},
Publisher = {O'Reilly Media},
Series = {Definitive Guide Series},
Title = {Dojo: The Definitive Guide},
Year = {2009}}
```

The output is:

[image]

I want to update the `pagetracker` option. Before it was set to `page` to create "ibid."-citations if the same reference appears again on the page. That style applied fine, but as I changed it to `false` the newly generated document does not update the citation style. I mark citations in the text with `\parencite`. So I want it to print three times the full citation again (see Russell 2009, p. X).

I tried to compile with the four steps to update the bibliography:
    pdflatex -shell-escape test.tex
    bibtex test
    pdflatex -shell-escape test.tex
    pdflatex -shell-escape test.tex

Second thing I tried is to delete the `aux` files manually, but that hasn't changed anything either.

Anyone got an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If you want to use `bibtex` to compile it, you have to add `backend=bibtex` to the options when calling `biblatex`

Comment: I updated my question and added a minimum working example. Adding the backend=bibtex option gave me no luck either :(

Comment: Probably the style `authoryear-icomp` sets automatically `pagetracker=true`.

Comment: The `pagetracker` setting just configures the page spread for abbreviations. If you want to disable *ibidem* abbreviations entirely, you have to set `ibidtracker=false` or better use `style=authoryear-comp`. Note that settings are applied in the order given; you can override style settings by specifying the `style` option first.

Comment: @Audrey Please make that an answer

Answer (score 2):

The `pagetracker` setting just configures the page spread for abbreviations. If you want to disable *ibidem* abbreviations entirely, you have to set `ibidtracker=false` or better use `style=authoryear-comp`. Note that settings are applied in the order given; you can override style settings by specifying the style option first.